# PHPUnit equalTo on dates with delta

Tags: php, phpunit

I've got a problem in PHPUnit where I would like to use delta parameter in equalTo method when comparing dates. 
Let say I want to treat dates as equal if they differ in no more than 10 seconds. What would be appropriate value of $some_delta? 10? 10000? Or something totally different?

```
$this->_restClient->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('getData')
    ->with(
        $this->equalTo(array('1')),
        $this->equalTo(array('2')),
        $this->equalTo($this->_date, $some_delta),
        $this->equalTo(null),
    )
    ->will($this->returnValue($this->_restResponses['generalRestResponse']));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### PHPUnit >= 7.5 (DateTime)

```
class MyDatesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testAllDateOk() {
        $date1 = new DateTime('2019-01-01 00:00:00');
        $date2 = new DateTime('2019-01-01 00:00:03');

        // ± 5 seconds are equals
        $this->assertEqualsWithDelta($date1->getTimestamp(), $date2->getTimestamp(), 5);
        // ± 1 second are distinct
        $this->assertNotEqualsWithDelta($date1->getTimestamp(), $date2->getTimestamp(), 1);
    }
}
```

### PHPUnit >= 7.5 (Carbon)

```
class MyDatesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testAllDateOk() {
        $date1 = Carbon::now();
        $date2 = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3);

        // ± 5 seconds are equals
        $this->assertEqualsWithDelta($date1->timestamp, $date2->timestamp, 5);
        // ± 1 second are distinct
        $this->assertNotEqualsWithDelta($date1->timestamp, $date2->timestamp, 1);
    }
}
```

Explanation: assertEquals with 4 params is deprecated since PHPUnit 8

Answer (score 45):

#### The delta values just needs to be the number of seconds

You need the seconds the timestamps can differ as the `4th parameter to assert equals` or in your case the `2nd to equalTo`. Both of those functions ( [`assertEquals`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php#L337) / [`equalTo`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php#L2259) ) point to `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual` so the delta handling is the same.

### Sample:

```
<?php

class foo extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testDateDiffsWorks() {
        $date1 = new DateTime('2011-01-01 00:00:00');
        $date2 = new DateTime('2011-01-01 00:00:03');

        $this->assertEquals($date1->getTimestamp(), $date2->getTimestamp(), '', 5);
    }

    public function testDateDiffsFails() {
        $date1 = new DateTime('2011-01-01 00:00:00');
        $date2 = new DateTime('2011-01-01 00:00:03');

        $this->assertEquals($date1->getTimestamp(), $date2->getTimestamp(), '', 0.5);
    }

}
```

#### And the output

The first test works the second fails.

```
phpunit test.php
PHPUnit 3.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) foo::testDateDiffsFails
Failed asserting that <integer:1293836403> matches expected <integer:1293836400>.

/home/edo/test.php:16
```

Comment: It also works when passing the DateTime objets without converting them to timestamp: `$this->assertEquals($date1, $date2, '', 5);`. (Tested in version 4.8)

Comment: This is no longer true since the API has changed and delta was removed from `assertEquals`. Use `assertEqualsWithDelta` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Addition to edorian answer - since PhpUnit v7.5 you can use `assertEqualsWithDelta()`, `assertEquals()` is deprecated since PhpUnit v8